# Uniform convergence of reciprocal polynomials

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $(P_n)_n$ be a sequence of self-reciprocal (named also palyndromic) polynomials that converges uniformly on $[a,b]$ with $a,b$ two reals. Can anything of speacial be told about the limit (more than the limit is continuous ...)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "reciprocal polynomials?" Rational functions?

Comment: Edited to avoid confusion

Comment: Is $P_n$ of degree $n$?

Comment: A polynomial is reciprocal if $x^nP(1/x) = P(x)$ where $n$ is the degree of $P$. Examples: $x^2-x+1, 3x^3-2x^2-2x+3$.